# Allowed Port Range for TCP

Tags: java, tcp

I am trying to generate a random port number for a TCP connection. From : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers I know that the range of ports is from 1024 to 49151 are not reserved, but some of them are UDP only, how can I generate only valid TCP port numbers?

Comment: Everything above 1024 is considered fine for a TCP client.  You're thinking about this too much if you need to see an entry on a wikipedia page for it to be an 'acceptable' TCP port.  All TCP ports =<1024 are acceptable for client socket source ports.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you bind to port 0, the OS will select a valid, not-in-use port.

If you need random as opposed to arbitrary, anything from 49152–65535 should be safe for automatic use like this, so just select a random number within that range. (you may have to retry if that port turns out to be in use, however.)

Comment: So any port within that range would support TCP? because from the wiki page, some ports are only marked for UDP. Also, how would I check in java if a port is in use? thanks!

Comment: All ports from 1–65535 support TCP, the TCP/UDP listed on that page refers to registered ports; that is, ports that are assigned for a specific use. Checking if a port is in-use is generally just done by trying to bind to it, if you get an error back about the port being in use, then it is. If it doesn't matter what port you get, but just that you get one, then you should bind port 0, and then get the local port off your new socket to find out what you got.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, your local server binds to a specific port but UDP and TCP are in different "namespaces" and so are independent.  Servers that use _both_ will typically open the same port number for both.  _Connections_ are defined by a 5-tuple of protocol, local-addr, local-port, remote-addr, remote-port which explains why you don't get cross-talk and the like.